# Convert nested json object in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, nested

I've been playing with json objects & using ReactJS. One of the json object represented by variable 'res'. How do I convert 'res' into 'b'.  I'm also getting my json object 'res' from an api.

I've reciprocated my problem over this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-leaf-sznhx?file=/src/App.js

```
const [res, setResult] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries").then(response => {
        setResult(response.data);
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

How do I convert this:

```
        const a = 
        {
          "menu_1": {
            "id": "1",
            "menuitem": [{
              "value": "0",
              "onclick": "0()"
            }, {
              "value": "0",
              "onclick": "0()"
            }]
          },
          "menu_2": {
            "id": "2",
            "menuitem": [{
              "value": "2",
              "onclick": "2()"
            }]
          }
        }
```

into this json object:

```
const b =

    {
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [
          {
            "value": "0",
            "onclick": "0()"
          },
          {
            "value": "0",
            "onclick": "0()"
          },
          {
            "value": "2",
            "onclick": "2()"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```js
const a = {
  menu_1: {
    id: "1",
    menuitem: [{
      value: "1",
      onclick: "1()",
    }, ],
  },
  menu_2: {
    id: "2",
    menuitem: [{
      value: "2",
      onclick: "2()",
    }, ],
  },
};

let b = Object.keys(a).reduce(
  (p, c) => {
    for (let item of a[c].menuitem) {
      p.popup.menuitem.push(item);
    }
    return p;
  }, {
    popup: {
      menuitem: []
    }
  }
);

console.log(b);
```

I'm assuming that object `a` might have more than one `menuitem` in the array.

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: My console.log prints this
`{
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": []
  }
}`

Comment: Can you print what are you passing inside the `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce this way

```js
const a = {
  "menu_1": {
    "id": "1",
    "menuitem": [{
      "value": "0",
      "onclick": "0()"
    }, {
      "value": "0",
      "onclick": "0()"
    }]
  },
  "menu_2": {
    "id": "2",
    "menuitem": [{
      "value": "2",
      "onclick": "2()"
    }]
  }
}

const res = Object.values(a).reduce((all, {
  menuitem
}) => {
  all.popup.menuitem = [...all.popup.menuitem, ...menuitem]

  return all
}, {
  popup: {
    menuitem: []
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: My console.log prints this { "popup": { "menuitem": [] } }

Comment: I have just added a sandbox link and more info for reference

Comment: you should create a helper function then you in the promise when getting your data you can called it to format the data then put it in the state